# Creating an android native button with unity side onclick processing

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have to add some android native UIs.
I want to process some at java side, and pass it to unity's handler.
Must I use `UnitySendMessage`?
Or can I replace the functionality of `View.OnClickListener` with a c# side function? ; processing all at unity side.